# Chartjs not displaying timed data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I'm new to chartjs, but after googling around, i still cannot figure out, why would I not get data charted out. I'm using "parser" attribute to parse string and providing expected display format with min/max values, but no data is shown

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
    labels:  ["labelA", "labelB"],
    datasets: [{
        data: ["10:32", "00:12"],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
    },
    options: {
    responsive: 'true',
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            parser: 'm:s',
            unit: 'minute',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            min: '00:00',
            max: '20:00',
            displayFormats: {
            'minute': 'mm:ss'
            }
        }
        }]
    }
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your code looks good and should work. Semantically, however, the use of the timeline is not quite correct. Your bars actually represent durations.

Please have a look at your amended code that works now with durations instead of times:

```js
function asSeconds(value) {
  const tokens = value.split(':');
  return Number(tokens[0]) * 60 + Number(tokens[1]);
}

function format(seconds) {
  return moment.utc(seconds * 1000).format("mm:ss");
}

new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['labelA', 'labelB'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: ['10:32', '00:12'].map(v => asSeconds(v)),
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: 'true',
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 60,
          max: asSeconds('20:00'),
          callback: s => format(s)
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => format(data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index])
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="80"></canvas>
```