# Display how many hours a user spent on a project with chartjs and react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to use chartjs to display how many hours a user spent on a poject.
im using time on yAxis but the maximum is 12hrs but i need unlimited hours count for example

```js
 scales: {
              x: {
                stacked: true,
              },
              y: {
                stacked: true,
                type: "time",
                time: {
                  tooltipFormat: "HH:mm",
                  parser: "HH:mm",
                  unit: "minute",
                  stepSize: 30,
                  displayFormats: {
                    minute: "HH:mm",
                    hour: "HH:mm",
                  },
                },
              },
```

example:

can someone help me please

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html <- have you tried using `max` for `y`?

Comment: i did but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833587/2358409